# Importing css file

Tags: css, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a web project that and i got confused when i saw this in my head tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

The last two lines are making imports into my app, but I've no files named `ccs` inside Content directory, and it comes worst when I have no directory named bundles, but incredibly it works!

Someone could to explain it to me?

PS.:

Directories structure:

```
CSS
|
|->bootstrap.css
|->bootstrap.min.css
|->Site.css
```

and I found a file named Modernizr inside Scripts directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's calling the files included in that particular bundle which is declared inside the BundleConfig class in the App_Start folder.

In that particular case The call to  `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` is calling `"~/Content/site.css"`

You can read [this](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/noel-rice/2012/09/19/adding-your-own-scripts-and-style-sheets-to-mvc-4-bundles) document for more understanding about @Styles.Render() and @Scripts.Render() methods.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, in some versions of .NET MVC (using Visual Studio), you (or someone else) can setup a `BundleConfig.cs`file in your project. When you open the file ((mine is located in App_Start > BundleConfig.cs), you'll see bundle registrations. This is a .NET bundler that includes various groups of files.

Depending on your app, it can be useful to create groups or bundles of files that are dependent upon one another, but can easily be included or omitted from a _Layout file for optimization.

Here's an example of one of our bundles for our company editor (which by it's name, is all the scripts we need for our company editor, and nothing else):

```
bundles.Add(
  CreateScriptBundle("~/bundles/crm/companyeditor")
  .Include("~/Scripts/app/CRM/CompanyEditor/commonEvents.min.js")
  .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/app/CRM/CompanyEditor", "*.min.js", false)
  .Include("~/Scripts/app/RFQOffering/RFQs.min.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/app/RFQOffering/editSubscriptions.min.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/app/Quotes/sentQuotesEditorView.min.js")
);
```

So instead of including a `<script src=""></script>` for each of those files, we created a bundle and just use the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/crm/companyeditor")` in our `_Layout` file for the company editor (in our case).